# Object to datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have the following problem:

[image]

I want to import this column's data from object to datetime like so:

```
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Unnamed: 0'], format = '%Y.%m.%d.')
```

But I get the following message:

```
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py in _array_strptime_with_fallback(arg, name, tz, fmt, exact, errors, infer_datetime_format)

    434 
    435     try:
--> 436         result, timezones = array_strptime(arg, fmt, exact=exact, errors=errors)
    437         if "%Z" in fmt or "%z" in fmt:
    438             return _return_parsed_timezone_results(result, timezones, tz, name)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\tslibs\strptime.pyx in pandas._libs.tslibs.strptime.array_strptime()

ValueError: time data '2020.01.01' does not match format '%Y.%m.%d.' (match)
```

Can anybody help me with this problem please?
Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Hi @Kbalint98, there seems to be a dot and space too many at the end of your time format : '%Y.%m.%d.' this should probably be '%Y.%m.%d'

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the dot at the end! :-)

```
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Unnamed: 0'], format = '%Y.%m.%d')
```